# How to get WSDL by request to Siebel Inbound WebService?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, siebel

Usually Web-services return WSDL by request like this:

http://web_server_host.com/WS_virtual_folder/?wsdl

I've created Siebel Inbound WS. 
URL of my WS looks like this:

http://web_server_host/eai_enu/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&SWEExtCmd=Execute&UserName=SADMIN&Password=passwrd

There is a possibility to generate WSDL in the Siebel UI by clicking the button "Generate WSDL".
I tried to make my WS to return WSDL: I added one more parameter **&wsdl** to URL of my WS.
It doesn't work:
When I request URL by web-browser (only URL is sending, there is no soap-message) - I get error like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Supplied input is not well formed or does not contain the expected data.(SBL-EAI-00137)</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <siebelf:siebdetail>
                    <siebelf:logfilename>EAIObjMgr_enu_0026_27262989.log</siebelf:logfilename>
                    <siebelf:errorstack>
                        <siebelf:error>
                            <siebelf:errorcode>SBL-EAI-00137</siebelf:errorcode>
                            <siebelf:errorsymbol>IDS_EAI_WS_BAD_XML_DOCUMENT</siebelf:errorsymbol>
                            <siebelf:errormsg>Supplied input is not well formed or does not contain the expected data.(SBL-EAI-00137)</siebelf:errormsg>
                        </siebelf:error>
                        <siebelf:error>
                            <siebelf:errorcode>SBL-EAI-00246</siebelf:errorcode>
                            <siebelf:errorsymbol>IDS_XMLCNV_ERR_EMPTYMSG</siebelf:errorsymbol>
                            <siebelf:errormsg>XML Hierarchy Converter error - empty input message, expecting an XML document in <Value> of input arguments(SBL-EAI-00246)</siebelf:errormsg>
                        </siebelf:error>
                    </siebelf:errorstack>
                </siebelf:siebdetail>
            </detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This response (error) is the same for both URL (with or without parameter &wsdl)

When I request URL by SoapUI (soap-message is sending) - I get again same response for both URL (with or without parametr &wsdl)

Is there such possibility: to get WSLD from Siebel Inbound WS by requesting URL?
I haven't found any mentions about it in the bookshelf.

Thanks in advance.
Sergey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siebel WSDLs cannot be generated from URLs like an Axis service. The onlyway is to login to the application and click on the Generate WSDL button in the Webservices screen.